# Different size of forms even though they have the same size

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have 4 images here. I am using Visual Studio 2019.
[image: 1st Image]

[image: 2nd Image]

As you can see there, they have the same width and height.
But when I run the program this comes out.
[image: 3rd Image]

[image: 4th Image]

As you can see. They are not even the same size, not even close at all. How to fix this?

What I remembered doing is when I was fixing the fonts in Add Operation. It suddenly auto adjusted its size and it became like that. I would want Record to do the same.

Comment: See the IDE warning message. The yellow bar behind the Form. Don't scale (> 100%) the display of the developing environment. Also, your app should be Dpi-Aware.

Comment: Please check the **AutoScaleMode** property.